# Tag a Repo from a Jenkins Bash Script

Tags: bash, git, jenkins

I recently read a post called "Tag a Repo from a Jenkins Workflow Script", my question is pretty similar but using a bash script (not a workflow script)

Inside of my script I have

```
#!/bin/bash

...

git push origin :refs/tags/${NEW_TAG}
git tag -fa $NEW_TAG
git push origin master --tags
```

but at first "git" command I've got

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please check `origin` url by using command `git remote -v`.

Please change `origin` url to `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com....` and it will work.

In non interactive mode you need to specify credentials in remote url.